# Upgrade MAC OS X

Tags: macos

I want to upgrade my leopard osx to snow leopard, and i want to know if it will erase my data or will only upgrade the OS and leave all my data and app intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Snow Leopard installer can upgrade in-place without having to format your drive or delete your files.

Having said that, make sure you're backed-up first in case something goes wrong.

I've seen it suggested that a clean install (then re-installing apps you actually use, and restoring your files from backup) is likely to be faster, more stable etc. I believe the expected benefit is due to losing old and unused apps, orphaned config and other cruft, so it would depend heavily on the starting state of your system; it's also significantly more manual effort.  YMMV.

Comment: thanks, i dont have so many app, but i need the most and i am from CApe Verde so the net here to expensive to download again all the update ant the app i need, so i dont want to do a clean install right now

Answer (score 1):

It won't erase your data. It will only update the system and the rest will be good to go.

Comment: uhm ok thanks, i will upgrade in right now, regards